# How to look through each table row?

Tags: jquery

How can I change the jquery variable below so that it looks for thorugh each row in the qandtbl?

Below is the varaible:

```
 var context = $('#qandatbl');
```

Below is qandatbl

```
<table id="qandatbl" align="center">

<tr>
    <td class="option">Option Type</td>
    <td class="noofanswers">Number of Answers</td>
    <td class="answer">Answer</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var context = $('#qandatbl tr');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var rows = context.children("tr");
```